# Which modern methods of antibiotic production are there?

Tags: biochemistry, health, antibiotics

For my seminar paper in the field of biology, I have to collect modern methods of antibiotic production. The topic is a little overwhelming, but the work should also be quite extensive (approx. 18 pages).

I've already done some research, but most of the results don't help me. I would be very grateful for a few web links and keywords that I could research for in order to break down the topic.

I will visit the university library in the next few days. It would help me a lot if someone could recommend a few good books references.

Comment: Are you interested in antibiotic production (so via chemical synthesis, metabolic engineering of microrganisms or fungi, etc..) or antibiotic R&D (compounds library screening, drug design, protein-protein interactions..) ?

Comment: I remember being told that making antibiotics against gram negative bacteria is a little bit more challenging than gram positive due to outer membrane differences. As such I'd recommend reading this paper which is great (Predictive compound accumulation rules yield a broad-spectrum antibiotic): https://www.nature.com/articles/nature22308 They dissect the efficacy of antibiotics for gram negative bacteria by outlining certain requirements, such as rigidity, globularity, presence of amine groups, and amphiphilicity. Also molecular weight, and polarity play a role.

Answer (score -1):

For Penicillin production try from page 165 of:

Industrial Microbiology: An Introduction

by

Michael J. Waites

Neil L. Morgan

John S. Rockey

Gary Higton

There is also a table in that chapter listing the other antibiotics and which organisms are used to produce the basic form.

I found it very readable.